# Illegal character in query at index 40: facebook

Tags: facebook, apache-camel, jbossfuse

Sorry, I am reformulating the question; I was so frustrated by this Error that I posted the question in a snap.

I am trying to use camel-facebook component and using very simple route that figures as such in the blueprint.xml file:

from uri="facebook://me?oAuthAppId={{oAuthAppId}}&oAuthAppSecret={{oAuthAppSecret}}&oAuthAccessToken={{oAuthAccessToken}}&consumer.delay=86400000"/>

I am using :
Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio
Version: 10.1.0.GA

Actually I see the bundle started :
[ 348] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   80] MyApp [fbdemo] (1.0.0.SNAPSHOT)

Also :
[ 333] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] camel-facebook (2.17.0.redhat-630187)

Perhaps I have the error mentioned above, I put XXXXXXXXX for oAuth*.

2017-02-14 16:02:16,128 | ERROR | 68)-192.168.56.1 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 234 - org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Error occurred during starting Camel: CamelContext(blueprintContext) due Failed to create route fbRoute: Route(fbRoute)[[From[facebook://me?oAuthAppId={{oAuthAppId}}... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: facebook://me?oAuthAppId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
&oAuthAppSecret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&oAuthAccessToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&consumer.delay=86400000 due to: Illegal character in query at index 40: facebook://me?oAuthAppId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
&oAuthAppSecret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&oAuthAccessToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&consumer.delay=86400000
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route fbRoute: Route(fbRoute)[[From[facebook://me?oAuthAppId={{oAuthAppId}}... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: facebook://me?oAuthAppId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
&oAuthAppSecret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&oAuthAccessToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&consumer.delay=86400000 due to: Illegal character in query at index 40: facebook://me?oAuthAppId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Shall the oAuthAccessToken be the Application AccesToken or User AccessToken that I get from Facebook Graph Explorer. Note that I don`t have any special character in code secret only a | ( pipe) in case the AccessToken is the Appli AccessToken not User AccessToken. How to figure the index 40.

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you cooperate too by formatting your error message properly so we can have a better clue as to the problem?

Comment: Find the character at position 40 into that facebook url which has an invalid. Its likely something in your oAuthAppId value

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xml then you need to check that all "&" symbols are encoded as "&" so it will looks like:

```
<from url="facebook://me?oAuthAppId=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;oAuthAppSecret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;oAuthAccessToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;consumer.delay=86400000" />
```